# Spring Security with overlapping configurations checks authorization in multiple <http> blocks

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have an application using Spring Security 4.2.18 with the security configured in xml. Right now I am introducing Spring Boot 2.5.4 in the project. Since upgrading, I have a problem with the configuration of security for some requests.

I have a  block matching specific requests and one matching the rest of all requests.

```
<http pattern="/api/**" use-expressions="true" authentication-manager-ref="apiAuthenticationManager" >
    <http-basic/>

    <intercept-url pattern="/api/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_API')"/>
    <csrf disabled="true"/>
</http>


<http pattern="/**" auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" create-session="always" disable-url-rewriting="true"
      authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
    <form-login login-processing-url="/resources/j_spring_security_check" login-page="/login"
                username-parameter="j_username"
                password-parameter="j_password"
                authentication-failure-url="/login?login_error=t" default-target-url="/redirectlogin"/>
    <logout logout-url="/resources/j_spring_security_logout"/>

    ...

    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>

    ...

</http>

<authentication-manager id="apiAuthenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="apiUserDetailsService">
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

The `ApiUserDetailsService` follows the specification:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class ApiUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    ...
    
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {
        boolean foundAccount = apiConfig.getUsername().equals(username);
        if (foundAccount) {
            return new User(username, apiConfig.getPassword(), singletonList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_API")));
        }
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Could not finder user with name " + username);
    }

}
```

If I make a request to something under `/api` and use incorrect Basic auth credentials, I previously got a 401 Unauthorized response. Since upgrading I get redirected to `/login` and end up in a redirect loop since the credentials are used there as well.

If I remove the `<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>` in the second `<http>` block, I get the expected behaviour.

How can I configure my application so that my request doesn't try to authorize using the rules in the second `<http>` block? I have tried using an `EntryPoint` but it isn't called before the user is erroneously authorized using the method of the generic `<http>` block.

Comment: It may may help to trace the request through the filter chain by enabling TRACE logging for Spring Security `logging.level.org.springframework.security=TRACE`. I suspect the request is processed by the first `<http>` block, and then a redirect causes is to enter the second `<http>` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't that the configurations were overlapping but rather that the failed authentication was redirected to `/login` which in turn was handled by the second `<http>` configuration.

I solved it by creating an implementation of `AuthenticationEntryPoint` that sets the `401 Unathorized` status on the response:

```
@Component
public class BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) {
        response.setStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());
    }
}
```

and in turn referencing to this in my basic authentication configuration:

```
<http pattern="/api/**" use-expressions="true" authentication-manager-ref="apiAuthenticationManager" >
    <http-basic entry-point-ref="basicAuthenticationEntryPoint"/>

    <intercept-url pattern="/api/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_API')"/>
    <csrf disabled="true"/>
</http>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting `<intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="permitAll" />` right above your `<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>` like:

In the second http block:

```java
...
<intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="permitAll" />
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
...
```

Comment: The issue is not that I wan't to be able to view the /login page, it is that my api calls are redirected to /login when they should get 401 reponses.